# Which browsers support text-shadow in ::selection

Tags: cross-browser, selection, css

Trying to get some documentation on this. Have seen it used in some websites where they declare `text-shadow` in their `::selection` pseudo element. Does anybody know if IE supports shadows on selected text? I know Firefox does not. Which browsers support `text-shadow` in `::selection`? Thanks.

Comment: The text-shadow property is supported in all major browsers, except Internet Explorer.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this site for testing is http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-shadow.  Just change the code to `h1::selection {text-shadow:2px 2px #FF0000;}`, then test on your choice of browsers by highlighting over the H1 text in the window after you click the "Click Me" button.

IE9 does not support `text-shadow` at all, so within a `::selection` it definitely wouldn't work.  Chrome, however, does support text-shadow within a `::selection`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about that issue:

[he W3C working draft for the ::selection pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#UIfragments)

[The Mozilla Developer Network on the ::-moz-selection and ::selection pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3a%3aselection)

And you can use [this page](http://themousepotatowebsite.co.za/the-text-selection-pseudo-element/) as a test base (just open it on the desirable browser)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's an ongoing discussion on supporting `text-shadow` inside `::selection` in Firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=721750